# Linq fluent vs Linq select on booleans

Tags: c#, linq

Alright Linq'ers. Try this one out.

Why would

```
NextActioners.Select(n => n.NextActioner.Equals(true));
```

incorrectly find 2 records,

but

```
from a in NextActioners where (a.NextActioner.Equals(true)) select a;
```

correctly find none?

On my good'ol Linqpad:

```
    public class AppPerson
        {
            public string PersonId;
            public string FullName;
            public string Role;
            public bool NextActioner;
        }

    void Main()
    {
        var NextActioners = new List<AppPerson> {
                    new AppPerson{FullName="testFullname1", NextActioner=false},
                    new AppPerson{FullName="testFullname2", NextActioner=false},
                };

        //Are all the NextActioners 'nextActioner' value false
        var noApproversSelected = NextActioners.All(a => a.NextActioner.Equals(false));
        Console.WriteLine("noApproversSelected={0}",noApproversSelected.ToString());//Result = true

        var listOfApprovers = from a in NextActioners
                        where (a.NextActioner.Equals(true))
                        select a;
        Console.WriteLine("listOfApprovers.Count()={0}",listOfApprovers.Count().ToString());//Result = 0

        var listOfApprovers1 = NextActioners.Select(n => n.NextActioner.Equals(true));
        Console.WriteLine("listOfApprovers1.Count()={0}",listOfApprovers1.Count().ToString());//Result = 2!!!!!!!

        var listOfApprovers2 = NextActioners.Select(n => n.NextActioner == true);
        Console.WriteLine("listOfApprovers2.Count()={0}",listOfApprovers2.Count().ToString());//Result = 2!!!!!!!

        var listOfApprovers3 = NextActioners.Select(n => n.NextActioner);
        Console.WriteLine("listOfApprovers3.Count()={0}",listOfApprovers3.Count().ToString());//Result = 2!!!!!!!

    }
```

Comment: Because you are projecting every actioner in that list, not filtering. That should probably be a `Where()` call.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe those two queries should do the same thing?  I am interested to learn why people believe false things about LINQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using

```
NextActioners.Select(n => n.NextActioner.Equals(true));
```

you are not doing any filtering. Select operator only transforms result of one type to result of a different type. In order to filter the results you need to use Where operator, like this:

```
var listOfApprovers1 = NextActioners.Where(n => n.NextActioner.Equals(true)).Select(n=>n);
```

Comment: `.Select(n => n)` is pointless.

Comment: @CarstenKönig I think that if your iterator has these side effects, you have a bigger problems to begin with :)

Comment: @CarstenKönig might be true, but seeing people being rude, doesn't mean being rude is ok ... :)

Comment: @Noctis ? what? - don't know what I missed there - I did not want to be rude at all and I did not see anyone beeing rude - as you might have seen I removed the comments as they where just *wrong* - and the "doh" was a sound of self-contempt (http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/pictures/homer/homer-doh.png)

Comment: @CarstenKönig nononon ... sorry ... i think you misunderstood me ... what i meant is: I don't think that having side effects to your iterator is a good thing. I've seen many bad things in code, but I don't think we should do those things. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: `Select(n=>n)` is pointless in this particular case but not in every case. The query `from n in c select n` generates `(c).Select(n=>n)` -- do you see why?

Comment: @EricLippert To hide the original type from the caller?

Comment: @EricLippert also, the fact that `Enumerable.Select` does not change the collection when called with *identity* lambda doesn't mean other `Select` method can't. Query syntax is not bind to `IEnumerable` or any other particular interface after all. It's based on names of the methods. So some other `Select` method might have different behavior and change the collection or do some other stuff underneath.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Hiding the original type from the caller is good but there is a deeper problem that it solves. One expects that the result of a query expression cannot be used to modify the collection.